# Nonlinear dynamical system with non isolated critical points

Tags: dynamical-systems

I am currently working on the system:

\begin{align}
  \dot x = y, \ \ \dot y = -x-yz, \ \ \dot z = -xz + 7x^2 
\end{align}

The critical points of this system are the whole of z-axis and that can be easily calculated. The positive part of z-axis is an attractor manifold based on the eigenvalues of the system at a critical point $(0,0,z_0)$ which are:
\begin{align*}
   \lambda_1 = \frac{-z_0}{2} - \sqrt{\frac{z_0^2}{4} - 1} =  \frac{- z_0}{2} -\frac{1}{2} \sqrt{z_0^2 -4}\\
\lambda_2 = \frac{-z_0}{2} + \sqrt{\frac{z_0^2}{4} - 1} =  \frac{-z_0}{2} +\frac{1}{2} \sqrt{z_0^2 -4} \\ \lambda_3 =0
\end{align*}

I am actually trying to find the limit $\lim_{t \to \infty}z(t)$. For every initial point I get different limit based on the graph but I would like to know how to find analytically this limit.